# how to set dynamic data to other html from ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax success response from one html but I want to set dynamic data of this ajax response to another how do I do that 
here is my ajax report

```
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        for (var i=0; i<data.data.length;i++)
        {
            $("#eng-jobs").append('<tr id="enginner-job'+[i]+'" class="price-table">' +'<td class="colspan-4">' + '<a href="job.html" class="title">' +data.data[i].job_name+'</a>' +'</td>' + '<td class="colspan-4">' + '<a href="job.html" class="location">' +data.data[i].location+'</a>' +'</td>' + '</tr>' );
        }
        window.location="enginnering.html";
    }
});
```

this will generate a dynamic table now I want to set this table in other html where I have put my code like

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead style="display: table-header-group;">
        <tr>
            <td class="colspan-4">Position</td>
            <td class="colspan-4 location-head">Location</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="eng-jobs">
        <!-- Table Body Data -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

but I got nothing Any help please

Comment: Do you want to show up in new window/tab?

Comment: yes and I think issue lies here

Answer (score 0):

Wrie this code in ajax success.

```
 window.open("enginnering.html");
```

Comment: sorry when I remove pop-up block page load but nothing to show there

Comment: @HimanshuGupta is there any content in page 'enginnering.html' ? or what is the exact location of 'engineering.html'?

Comment: yes there is content in engineering.html and this page is now loading but data not showing  I have put your code after success but nothing happening

Answer (score 0):

Try using `localStorage` , removing brackets `"["` `"]"` from string setting `id`

At `"engineering.html"`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
  // do stuff with `data`
})
```

at `success`

```
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
        for (var i=0; i<data.data.length;i++)
        {
            $("#eng-jobs").append('<tr id="enginner-job'+ i +'" class="price-table">' 
            + '<td class="colspan-4">' 
            + '<a href="job.html" class="title">' +data.data[i].job_name+'</a>' 
            + '</td>' 
            + '<td class="colspan-4">' 
            + '<a href="job.html" class="location">' + data.data[i].location
            + '</a>' 
            + '</td>' 
            + '</tr>' );
        }
        window.location = "enginnering.html";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

on success

try this

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var myObj=JSON.parse(data.data);

       $.each(myObj, function (index,item) {
            $("#eng-jobs").append('<tr id="enginner-job' + index + '" class="price-table">'
            + '<td class="colspan-4">'
            + '<a href="job.html" class="title">' + item.job_name + '</a>'
            + '</td>'
            + '<td class="colspan-4">'
            + '<a href="job.html" class="location">' + item.location
            + '</a>'
            + '</td>'
            + '</tr>');
        })
    window.location = "enginnering.html";
}
```

});

Comment: it is giving me error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o                  I have data in form of Object {data: Array[4]}           and data.data in form of [Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: can you send your one object